# Configuring AngularDart Modules

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to add an HttpInterceptor. In AngularJS I would write something like this:

```js
m.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {...}])
```

But it seems like there is no config function in AngularDart.

What is the right way to configure AngularDart modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HttpInterceptors are implemented slightly differently in AngularDart.

```dart
main() {
  // define your interceptor
  var intercept = new HttpInterceptor();
  intercept.request = (HttpResponseConfig requestConfig) => /* something */;
  intercept.response = (HttpResponse response) => /* something */;
  intercept.requestError = (dynamic error) => /* something */;
  intercept.responseError = (dynamic error) => /* something */;

  // get hold of the HttpInterceptors instance -- there are many ways to do this.
  Injector injector = ngBootstrap(/* ... */);
  var interceptors = injector.get(HttpInterceptors);

  // register/add your interceptor
  interceptors.add(intercept)
}
```

More info on the API:

http://ci.angularjs.org/view/Dart/job/angular.dart-master/javadoc/angular.core.dom/HttpInterceptors.html
http://ci.angularjs.org/view/Dart/job/angular.dart-master/javadoc/angular.core.dom/HttpInterceptor.html

Comment: This isn't the right way, pls look at my response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25096569/194642

Comment: Links are broken ):

Comment: HttpInterceptor class does not exist anymore in Dart 2.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @pavelgj is not entirely correct way to use `HttpInterceptor`s. It can introduce hard to debug timing errors, when certain Http calls would have been already initiated by bootstrapped angular-dart app, hence the interceptor would miss those calls.

The right way to use interceptor is to make sure that you inject it before the first Http call somewhere within your angular app. The new syntax of bootstrapping is this:

```
applicationFactory()
  .addModule(new YourAngularApp())
  .run();
```

So within YourAngularApp, wherever you are injecting `Http` for the first time, you can inject the `HttpInterceptor` (only once) and add your custom interceptor.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I initially used the selected answer but eventually ran into some timing issues when I tried injecting a service into my routes. The calls to my service were getting called before the interceptors were set up because routes get initialized right after run(). Setting up the interceptors inside of your app looks like a cleaner solution as well.