# Error when using HttpInterceptor.responseError in Angular Dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to do some HTTP request validation using a HttpInterceptor and its responseError property.

I found a bunch of examples on how to do this with regular AngularJS but so far no luck with Angular Dart, I only get an *Class 'String' has no instance getter 'iterator'* exception.

Also, I cannot find an equivalent of $q.reject(response); in Angular Dart, is it needed at all?

AngularJS example code:

```js
var interceptor = ['$location', '$q', function($location, $q) {
    function success(response) {
        return response;
    }

    function error(response) {

        if(response.status === 401) {
            $location.path('/login');
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
        else {
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    }

    return function(promise) {
        return promise.then(success, error);
    }
}];
```

My take:

```dart
@Injectable()
class MyService {

  HttpInterceptors interceptors;

  MyService(this.interceptors) {
    var intercept = new HttpInterceptor();
    intercept.responseError = (dynamic error) {
      return error;
    };
    interceptors.add(intercept);
}
```

[Update]
It seems like adding an interceptor with responseError messes up things.

```
Future _loadData() {
  return _http.get("http://localhost/file-that-doesnt-exist.json")
    .then((HttpResponse response) {  //<-- This gets called if I add an interceptor with a responseError
      _dataCache = new Map();
      print("MAPPING");
      for (Map post in response.data) {
        Post p = new Post.fromJsonMap(post);
        _dataCache[p.id] = p;
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: maybe the answer to this question has some useful information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913222

Comment: The interceptor is recognized and triggered properly but when trying to make use of responseError, everything fails. I've updated my Dart example to better describe my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. In order to not mess future listeners up, the responseError needs to send a Future.error.

Solution:

```
var intercept = new HttpInterceptor();
intercept.responseError = (dynamic error) {
  return new Future.error(error); //<-- return a Future.error
};
interceptors.add(intercept);
```